# Navigation bar disappear on Cancel of "Add to Exsting Contact" controller

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9

CNContactViewController for unknowncontact on tap of "Add to Existing Contact" present a view controller. When user selects cancel Navigation bar of CNContactViewController disappears and now there is no way to go back.

Answer (score 0):

There might be better ways to approach this, but this worked for me. Fixed by setting the left bar button item of the navigation bar of my instance of CNContactViewController to a new instance of the cancel button that dismisses the presented CNContactViewController. In code:

```
let contactVC = CNContactViewController(forUnknownContact: newContact)
contactVC.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, 
                                                 target: self, action: #selector(cancelAction))
```

I then call present and pass in contactVC. Then in cancelAction I called the dismiss function and it worked!